# Python overflow cause by product of many probabilities, inversion of a large covariance matrix, and computation of its determinant

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

So I have a function like this:

```
def logpp(X,m,S):
# Find the number of dimensions from the data vector
d = X.shape[1]

# Invert the covariance matrix
Sinv = np.linalg.inv(S)

# Compute the quadratic terms for all data points
Q = -0.5*(np.dot(X-m,Sinv)*(X-m)).sum(axis=1)

# Raise them quadratic terms to the exponential
Q = np.exp(Q)

# Divide by the terms in the denominator
P = Q / np.sqrt((2*np.pi)**d * np.linalg.det(S))

# Take the product of the probability of each data points
Pprod = np.prod(P)

# Return the log-probability
return np.log(Pprod)
```

As I generate larger input, the result will have an overflow. How to re-write inorder to avoid overflow?

My input function:

```
X1 = numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState(123).normal(0,1,[5,len(m1)])
X2 = numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState(123).normal(0,1,[20,len(m2)])
X3 = numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState(123).normal(0,1,[100,len(m3)])
```

Comment: And which line is the overflow at?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :-) You could also probably ask this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as that's a good place to get feedback and improvements for working code!

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis Hi, Thanks for your information, I will also post my question there

Comment: @Miguel Sinv = np.linalg.inv(S) This line will produce the first overflow, on the larget input matrix

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for pointing it out and the correction

Comment: @Rock And how do you call logpp? post the line where you call it please. Where do X1 X2 and X3 go?

Comment: and where does `m1` and `d` come from?

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis Considering the code doesn't work as intended, it's absolutely unfit for Code Review. Now the question was posted & closed there. Please consider carefully before directing unsuspecting users to sites you don't know the scope of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of pointers:

- note that when dealing with probabilities you normally want to stay in "log space" as everything is non-negative and code tends to use values that under/overflow floating point numbers easily
- linear algebra libraries have lots of tools for dealing with ill conditioned and other numerical instabilities, check out the [linalg tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html) for a few pointers

in your case I'd rewrite the function to be:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

def logpp(X, m, S):
    X = X - m
    Q = -0.5 * (linalg.solve(S, X.T).T * X).sum(axis=1)

    sgn, logdetS = np.linalg.slogdet(S)
    assert sgn > 0

    logP = Q - 0.5 * (np.log(2*np.pi)*d + logdetS)

    return np.sum(logP)
```

which is better behaved for me

I'm not entirely sure of the validity of using [`solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html) here, but I think it does the right thing.  if somebody could comment on this it would be great!

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is absolutely correct! I found another way to do it without using the solve function, I will post below

Answer (score 0):

Without using "slove" function:

```
def logp_robust(X,m,S):

# Find the number of dimensions from the data vector
d = X.shape[1]
N = X.shape[0]
# Invert the covariance matrix
Sinv = numpy.linalg.inv(S)

# Compute the quadratic terms for all data points
Q = numpy.sum(-0.5*(numpy.dot(X-m,Sinv)*(X-m)).sum(axis=1))


return (Q-0.5 * (d * N)* numpy.log(2*numpy.pi)-0.5* N* numpy.log(numpy.linalg.det(S)))
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `slogdet` if you can, I was getting overflows in larger tests without using it.  taking the log of a negative number will fail, so the `assert` is implied by your usage anyway

Comment: @SamMason ok, I will try it, thanks for the suggestion